# Junit for a method containing getClassLoader().getResource()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, easymock

I have the following service class in my code .

```
public class MyServiceImpl {

public List<Group> getGroups() throws JAXBException {
List<Group> viewModel = new ArrayList<Group>();
File file = new File(MyServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath());
.....
....
 }
}
```

I am trying to write a Junit for `getGroups()` method and am stuck with the line where I create a new file. I tried with EasyMock and Mockito but could not get it to work.

```
EasyMock.expect(MyServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath()).andReturn("path");
```

I am getting the following when the test is run.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysite.services.content.MyServiceImplTest.testGetGroups(MyServiceImplTest.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**edit**

Adding the test class.

```
public class MyServiceImplTest {

private MyServiceImpl service;

@Before
public void setup() {
    service = new MyServiceImpl();
}

@Test
public void testGetGroups() throws Exception {
    EasyMock.expect(MyServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath()).andReturn("path");

    service.getGroups();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the above issue by creating a test file `filename` and placing it in `src/test/resource` folder and when i run the test it passed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling EasyMocks's replay method with your mock as the parameter before calling the mocked method? If not, that might be why you're getting a Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Tried again after adding replay and verify methods but it didn't work. Edited the question to add the Test class.

Answer (score 0):

After adding your test class, I see the issue.

try this:

```
public class MyServiceImplTest {
    private MyServiceImpl service;

    @Before
     public void setup() {
          service = EasyMock.createMock(MyServiceImpl.class);
     }

     @Test
      public void testGetGroups() throws Exception {

      EasyMock.expect(MyServiceImpl.getClass.getClassLoader()
      .getResource("filename")
      .getPath())
      .andReturn("path");

       EasyMock.replay(service);
       //Do something with Mock
       EasyMock.verify(service);

 }
```

If you want to call service.getGroups() you need to either mock out that method call or use a partial mock. See here and search for partial mocking: [EasyMock Guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html)

Comment: The test is failing at the EasyMock.expect() line. Creating a mock of the class did not work.

Comment: Upon further inspection and some coffee, i noticed you are chaining method calls together and those return other objects that aren't being mocked. Since those objects are not being returned by the mock(read more about mocking if this isn't clear), you are just getting null back instead of what you're expecting. You would need to create a mock class loader and have the mock serviceimpl.class return that mock and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the mock here? Please read the EasyMock documentation because you haven't understood how a mock works.

You want `MyServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath()` to return a specific value. This is actually impossible to do. It would means to mock `MyServiceImpl.class` (impossible, at least easily) than a `ClassLoader`, and a `URI`.

But doing so is pointless. And the real question is: Why mocking that? This should have a known and definitive answer in your test environment. Just use that in your test.

If for some weird reason, you really want to change this answer, you should refactor your code and some method like

```
protected File getFileToMe() {
    return new File(getClass().getResource("/filename").getPath());
}
```

Then you can test be overriding the method using an anonymous inner class or a partial mock.